# Data interpolation not working in Angular html template

Tags: html, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a service that reads the data from Realtime Database
from `product.service.ts`:

```ts
getAll(){
    // Get All Products
    return this.db.list("/products").snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Which I use to read data in my `products.component.ts`:

```ts
products$:Observable<any>;
  
  constructor(productService : ProductService) {
    this.products$ = productService.getAll();
  }
```

But if I try and interpolate the values in my template it won't work. Doing

```html
<div *ngFor = "let p of products$ | async">
    <div>
        title: {{p.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Will render: "title:" , with no actual value interpolated.
What might the issue be?

If I look at the full object p, or even p.payload I can see that the data is loaded and correct, it just won't show

```html
{{ p | json}}
```

and

```html
{{ p.payload | json }}
```

both work as expected

Comment: When you say p and p.payload both work as expected, what are you seeing?

Comment: Please share the actual output of `p | json` along with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
constructor(productService : ProductService) {
    this.products$ = productService.getAll()
        .pipe(map( action => action
          .map(a => {
            return a.payload.val();
          })));
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on what your `key` variable is used for?

Comment: Ended up going for this approach since I ended up needing to manipulate the data before displaying anyways. Thanks Hamza!